# Where to write specification file for Flex?

Tags: compiler-construction, bison, flex-lexer

I want to perform some pattern matching using flex bison. I want to know how to use flex and where to create specification file for this (tools or software). And when the tokens are generated by flex, where to write specification file for bison. I want to know about Editors IDEs or tools. Can I perform all the tasks using Turbo C or what else is required?

Answer (score 1):

This question has not attracted an answer because it's asking for an introductory tutorial and there are plenty available online that any search engine could find.

One nice tutorial is here: http://aquamentus.com/flex_bison.html which answers most of these questions.

As a bison and flex file is a text file, it can be amended by any text editor, such as notepad, notepad++, vi, vim, emacs and so on. You did not specify what platform you would be running on. Visual Studio can even be configured to work with the tools, although it's a bit clunky. Yes: You can build the C output with Turbo C. The tools can also generate C++.

Most people would use GCC and command prompt builds for basic use of flex and bison.

I teach students this method. You can use my online videos if that helps:
[YouTube Channel on Flex and Bison](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL3czsVugafjNLmIHA8ODBxuwWy8W4Uk9h)